# Do I get any performance advantage by using RecyclerView for shorter data sets over NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

#### Question:

I have a NestedScrollView with 11 type of views (ImageView, 6 TextViews, 4 CardViews(with 1 RecyclerView in each)), the images of the layout is attached below. I am thinking of Implementing multi-view recyclerview rather than the nestedscrollview.

Do I get any performance improvements by using recyclerview?

#### Layout Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you read *that it's always better to use RecyclerView anywhere possible*?

Comment: I am not sure but, I was looking for another question on StackOverflow for multiview recyclerview and there somebody in the comments mentioned this and from there it's stuck in my head whether it's a thing or not.

Comment: You've provided very little information about your current situation, and your question of why is RV better for short data is unclear. Like, what is "short data"? Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to rephrase your question if you hope to garner any useful answers.

Comment: I have rephrased the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all of the advantage comes from recycling. If at least `all-1` items are always visible, you get no performance advantage. Instead you get disadvantage of not saving the state of child items (like scroll position of orthogonal sub-recyclers won't be preserved when navigating forward and back).

However, you do get the advantage of streamlining your workflow through commonality with other, recycler-based views.

I'm the kind of person who always uses `RecyclerView`, but I do it out of laziness.

Comment: Please have a look at the rephrased question I have added some layout images. Should I consider recyclerview with that?

Comment: @SiddharthaSrivastava ok, I thought the sub-recyclers are horizontal. In your case you might don't get this particular disadvantage. Also note that your sub-recyclers will never recycle, as they don't scroll, their parent is scrolling. "State Symbols" will most likely get recycled though. The rest stands: use what you're more comfortable with.

Comment: Ok @Agent_L thanks for the help, I will continue using NestedScrollView.